# How can I install Windows 10 32-bit disc on Windows 8.1 OEM 64-bit with embedded key?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

**Background**

Two months ago, one of my cousin bought a Lenovo Ideapad 100 notebook with Windows 8.1 single language OEM preinstalled on it. The notebook uses BIOS key to activate OEM genuine license.

Yesterday, he asked me how to upgrade his license to Windows 10 without downloading the installation media on his side, since every attempt he had taken to update on his own from internet were failed/stopped abruptly at low percentage progress (his internet provider might be slow, unable to deal longer with large files). Then he want to lend my Windows 10 media disc (of course without key) by agreement.

However, I realize that the disc used on my early-upgraded PC is suitable for 32-bit version of Windows 7/8/8.1, while the target system to upgrade has 64-bit version. We're in a hurry because Windows 10 free upgrade offer will end 2 days later.

**Problem Statement**

On his remaining time to upgrade into Windows 10 license for free, I have these 3 alternatives to upgrade his current system:

1. Install/upgrade with Windows 10 32-bit version I already have (compromising his OEM tools and probably also his OEM key),
2. Obtain 64-bit version from Microsoft site on my side (I afraid the upgrade may not execute immediately before time limit ends, consider more than 2 GB amount to download a proper media),
3. Buy a 64-bit version disc from nearest store then use it on target system (costs some amount of money which I should avoid this as I could).

I prefer the first choice since it requires less time and effort than others, but how I can upgrade it with his embedded key to obtain Windows 10 license as soon as possible?

Any kind of suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you have Windows 10 1511 Build 10586 [November Update] or newer:**
You can install W10 32-bit onto W8 64-bit. Skip entering product key if W10 setup ask for one during installation. After installation, W10 should detect W8 OEM key and activate it by digital entitlement automatically. If W10 does not activate automatically, you can enter W8 OEM key manually to activate. You may retrieve OEM key using [ShowKeyPlus](http://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/2577-showkey.html).

After successful activation, you can install and switch to W10 64-bit in your spare time, it will activate automatically since your HWID is already recorded by Microsoft.

**Otherwise:**
You can get updated W10 32/64-bit image using [Media Creation Tool](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-media-creation-tool-create-installation-media-upgrade).

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case, I recommend you use [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) on your side to download an install media. Then, you can use it to upgrade Windows 7/8/8.1, this should work even past the deadline.

You can also use this media to perform a fresh install of Windows 10, which you can do even with the OEM key for Win 8.1 (you may have to use phone activation though). This will work anytime (I did it on my own computer).